# Creating a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to create a chart having the hours(1- 24) on y-axis and the days(1-10) on the x-axis.Can anyone suggest a way to do it.

With the repeating numbers in the series to scatter at one point

Below is the code uinsg the chartistjs from http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  series: [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23]
}, {
  fullWidth: true,
  chartPadding: {
    right: 10
  },
  low: 0
});
```

Comment: *With the repeating numbers in the series to scatter at one point.* What do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** build any type of chart with `Chartist` using presented `data object`. Because `data object` can contain a lot of `series` but size of each of them should be the same as `labels` array size.

To implement

> With the repeating numbers in the series to scatter at one point

first of all you need to broke data to series. In your example each serie must contains 10 numbers (on for each of the 10 days). And may be you should try to use other type of chart i.e. [**line scatter**](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#line-scatter-random)